# Call JQZoom on AJAX Load()

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqzoom

Im using `C# MVC` as my Software. In my page, I Will have a partial View that show Images. Then I will bind these Images with `jqzoom`. I bind it inside `document ready` function and it work well. But every X minutes, I need to refresh my partial View and re-fetching it with new data from `DB`, then bind the new images with Jqzoom too. But then it shows alert 'problem while loading image'

DB would only return the `path string` to the image. So, theres a small possibility that the Image path is not exist. But for the current problem, all images are exist

Here is my code :

```
@Html.Resource(
    @<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.zoom').jqzoom({
                zoomType: 'standard',
                preloadImages: false,
                zoomWidth: 500,
                zoomHeight: 500,
                title: false
            });
            $('.zoomPad').css('z-index', 'auto');
        });

        setInterval(function () {
            $('#Display').load('@Url.Action("xx", "xx")', function () {
                $('.zoom').jqzoom({
                    zoomType: 'standard',
                    preloadImages: false,
                    zoomWidth: 500,
                    zoomHeight: 500,
                    title: false
                });
                $('.zoomPad').css('z-index', 'auto');
            });
        }, 1000 * 30 * 1);
    </script>, "js")
```

My Questions :

1. After some search and tried it so many times, I come out with the conclusion that calling `jqzoom` inside the `.load()` function would fire the error alert. How to call `jqzoom` after reload a partial View?
2. If some Image path does not exist, will it fire the error alert too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `jqzoom` inside `load()` would still fire the alert. the only workaround is to check every path image, whether its exist or not. after confirmed, then call the image and `jqzoom`